# best way to defer a function after another one in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-deferred

I tend to run into this problem quite often, and my solutions never really work the way i wanted to.
Basically,  I want one function to wait till the one before is completely finished running.
For example, I have a gps locating function, and i want another function to run once the gps one completes its tasks.
I am not putting any code for this because i would like to see how people do it without seeing my mine, as to be completely objective.

I am using phonegap, jquery-mobile and mkaing hybrid apps.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just do this ?

```
func1();
func2();
```

If it is more complicated than that, perhaps you messed up somewhere earlier in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.Deferred:

```
function locate() { 
   var d = $.Deferred();
   locationService.start().then(function(position) {
       d.resolve(position);
   });
   return d;
}

locate().then(function(position) {
    console.log('Latitude: ' + position.Latitude + ' - Longitude: ' + position.Longitude);
});
```

jQuery Api docs http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/

Comment: this looks not bad, i will check if it works properly